# Sending nested JSON from rails app to hapijs app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, node.js, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails 3.4, node 9, and Hapi js 16.5.2 

 What i'm trying to do is send a nested JSON from a rails app to a hapi js app, but something weird is happening. I am using the Rest-Client request for sending a POST request. the JSON is of the following format:

```
data = {
    time => {
        start => "12.11.17",
        end => "13.11.17"
    },
    event => "party"
}
```

The request is of the following form:

```
RestClient::Request.new(
    :method => :post,
    :url => "mynodeserverroute",
    :payload => data
).execute
```

The problem is all the nested elements are sent really weirdly, instead of being of the form:

```
time: {
        start: "12.11.17",
        end: "13.11.17"
    }
```

It comes back in the form

```
"time[start]": "12.11.17", 
"time[end]": "13.11.17"
```

Which makes it challenging to verify later of. 
What am I doing wrong? I tried adding the following to the request:

```
:header => {
            :content_type => :json, 
            :accept => :json
}
```

but that didn't help as well.
Is there a different method to send a JSON via rails?

Answer (score 0):

The data looks wierd. It should look something like:

```
"time":{"start":"12.11.17","end":"13.11.17"}
```

---

I don't know your setup. 
But i would start with a simple rails build-in respond_to do in a controller, with a corresponding route. And after that implementing the RestClient::Request.

For example:

```
#routes.rb
...
get '/this-url-is-for-seeing-the-data' => 'controller_name#post_this'
...
```

And then in the controller:

```
def post_this
  respond_to to |format|
    format.json { render json: { time: { start: "12.11.17", end: "13.11.17" } } }
  end 
end
```

You can now visit the url: `/this-url-is-for-seeing-the-data.json` and see the data in your browser.

Now you know it's right and you can build the rest, i hope :)

Good luck!